# Create granularity with flat docs in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

First, I don't know if my method of storing is the good one but I tried like this.
I want to create a form (in front) from dynamical data and create a select form from theses.

I have a collection in mongo where each field refer to an enum.

```
{
    {
        _id: "xxx",
        "Parent":"ParentEnum1",
        "firstChild": "firstChildEnum2",
        "secondChild": "secondChildEnum3",
        "thirdChild":"thirdChildEnum1",
    },
    {
        _id: "xxx",
        "Parent":"ParentEnum1",
        "firstChild": "firstChildEnum1",
        "secondChild": "secondChildEnum3",
        "thirdChild":"thirdChildEnum1",
    },
    {
        _id: "xxx",
        "Parent":"ParentEnum2",
        "firstChild": "firstChildEnum2",
        "secondChild": "secondChildEnum5",
        "thirdChild":"thirdChildEnum8,
    },
    {
        _id: "xxx",
        "Parent":"ParentEnum2",
        "firstChild": "firstChildEnum2",
        "secondChild": "secondChildEnum1",
        "thirdChild": null,
    },
    {
        _id: "xxx",
        "Parent":"ParentEnum4",
        "firstChild": "firstChildEnum4",
        "secondChild": "secondChildEnum1",
        "thirdChild":"thirdChildEnum5,
    },
    {
        _id: "xxx",
        "Parent":"ParentEnum1",
        "firstChild": "firstChildEnum4",
        "secondChild": "secondChildEnum5",
        "thirdChild":"thirdChildEnum7,
    },
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

from that documents, I want to obtain a hierarchical structure like this:

```
{

    "ParentEnum1":{
        firstChildEnum4:{
            secondChildEnum5:[
                thirdChildEnum7,
            ]
        },
        firstChildEnum1:{
            secondChildEnum3:[
                thirdChildEnum1,
            ]
        },
        firstChildEnum2:{
            secondChildEnum3:[
                thirdChildEnum1,
            ]
        }
    },
    "ParentEnum2":{
        "firstChildEnum2":{
            "secondChildEnum5":[
                "thirdChildEnum8"
            ],
            "secondChildEnum1":[]
        }
    },
    "ParentEnum4":{
        "firstChildEnum4":{
            "secondChildEnum5":[
                "thirdChildEnum7"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

For that I tried to use aggregation group, but I can only get the first granularity with a `$group` and a `$addToSet` one the `firstChild` field.
I think I can do better with `$bucket` but I tried with no success (Maybe I didn't use it properly)

I don't know if I what I want to do is possible, then I am open to any other suggestions.

Do you have an Idea of a pipeline operator to use if it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be there will be some more efficient ways, but this is the limited for 4 levels as per your requirement,

- `$gorup` by first top 3 levels and make array of third level field
- `$group` by first top 2 levels and make array of second level as k(key) and v(value) format
- `$group` by second 1 top level and make array of first level and  convert second level from array to object using `$objectToArray`
- convert second level from array to object using `$arrayToObject`, and make array of first level and convert to object using `$arrayToObject`,
- `$replaceRoot` to replace first level object to root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        Parent: "$Parent",
        firstChild: "$firstChild",
        secondChild: "$secondChild"
      },
      thirdChild: { $push: "$thirdChild" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        Parent: "$_id.Parent",
        firstChild: "$_id.firstChild"
      },
      secondChild: {
        $push: { k: "$_id.secondChild", v: "$thirdChild" }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.Parent",
      firstChild: {
        $push: { k: "$_id.firstChild", v: { $arrayToObject: "$secondChild" } }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: [[
          { k: "$_id", v: { $arrayToObject: "$firstChild" } }
        ]]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SzGLWc4SfYa)

Comment: Thank you a lot this is smart. I first tried to group id like you do, but the aggregator operator that I was missing was $push. Thank you !!